# move a div with respect to another one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

I don't exactly know how to formulate that question but 
basically my problem is the following : I have 2 divs that are draggable and I would like them to be be linked by smaller divs in between . So let say div A is a square at position 0 and div B is another square at position 10. how can i put div  C  in between them so that if I move div B or A , C stay in between.

from this :

```
A - - - - C - - - - B
```

to this

```
A
  -
    -
      - 
        -
          C
             -
               -
                 -
                   -
                     B
```

Is this even possible with divs?

Comment: Are you just trying to render a line to connect the 3 elements?

Comment: @MattBall  I was at first but i gave up because it seems to complicated ( to rotate properly) so now the dashes are just to show the space between each div

Comment: How about taking a completely different approach: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: @MattBall no this will not help me because of other things in my project... (and a huge time constant)

Answer (score 1):

A basic algorithm would be:

```
xCoord_ofC = (xCoord_ofA + xCoord_ofB) / 2;
yCoord_ofC = (yCoord_ofA + yCoord_ofB) / 2;
```

If you are using jQuery UI you can do it in the `drag` listener.